# question about wait-notify in java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Hi I'm studying the basics of java threads,
but I'd like to get some help because I don't understand the examples in the book.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnXkv.jpg

In this example, when the user presses any key,
the yellow bar is filled with magenta and the bar's magenta is
reduced by a thread.

But the part I don't understand is if you press the key for a long time while bar is full,
the magenta of the bar does not reduce immediately when the key is released

when I checked. the fill() function was running for a certain time even when the key was released.

I want to know, why if the bar is full and the key is pressed for a long time,
the fill() function works for a certain time even when the key is released
and the bar does not reduce immediately.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    private int barSize = 0;
    private int maxBarSize;
    
    public MyLabel(int maxBarSize) {
        this.maxBarSize = maxBarSize;
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        int width = (int) ( (   (double)(   getWidth()  )   )/maxBarSize    *barSize            );
        if (width == 0) return;
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, this.getHeight());
    }
    
    synchronized void fill() {
        if (barSize == maxBarSize) {        
            try {
                wait(); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return;
            }
        }
        
        barSize++;
        repaint();
        notify();
    }
    
    synchronized void consume() {
        if (barSize == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("consume");
        barSize--;
        repaint();
        notify();
    }
}

class ComsumerThread extends Thread {
    private MyLabel bar;
    
    public ComsumerThread(MyLabel bar) {
        this.bar = bar; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        while(true) {
            try {
                sleep(100);
                bar.consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TabAndThreadEx extends JFrame {
    private MyLabel bar = new MyLabel(100);
    
    
    public TabAndThreadEx(String title) {
        super(title);
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        bar.setBackground(Color.orange);
        bar.setOpaque(true);
        bar.setLocation(20, 50);
        bar.setSize(300, 20);
        c.add(bar);
        
        c.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                bar.fill();
            }
        });
        
        setSize(350, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        c.setFocusable(true);
        c.requestFocus();
        ComsumerThread th = new ComsumerThread(bar);
        th.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new TabAndThreadEx("Quickly press any key to fill the bar");
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might help to add log statements to see what's going on.

Comment: In your `fill()` method, you call the `wait()` method if the bar is full.  This means "pause this thread until this object is notified".  There is a call to `notify()` at the end of the `fill()` method, but the program will never get there because the thread is paused.  You also have another call to `notify()` in your `consume()` method.  This is the call that unpauses your `fill()` thread.  So the delay you are seeing is between the time you release the key, and the time your `ConsumerThread` calls `bar.consume()`.  It should always be less than a 100ms (0.1 second) delay, though.